# Select UIDs but not those with a given state?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]I am programming a simple Customer Database (Bridal Gowns) for my own business and try to reach the following goal:

I try to filter out those uids which do not have an "ordered = 1" flag. So, all the entries from a user, where at least one entry has an "ordered = 1" flag should not be shown.

In the picture below, all entries for user 575 should not be shown as he has already ordered one dress...

Can this be done?

Kind Regards,

Stefan

Comment: Hey OP, please don't use images in place of data, it makes it hard to answer the Q...

Comment: What are the queries you have tried? What DB are you using. I might try something like `Select uid from table_name where ordered=1`

Comment: Sorry for that: I have tried: SELECT  *
FROM    wccrm_anprobe an
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    wccrm_anprobe, wccrm_kunden
        WHERE  an.ordered <> '0' and
wccrm_anprobe.uid = wccrm_kunden.id
       
        )

group by an.uid - but this shows all entries even from user 575 which should not be shown...

Answer (score 1):

Use `not exists`

```
select a1.*
from MyTable a1
where not exists (select 1  
                  from MyTable a2
                  where ordered = 1
                  and a1.UID = a2.UID)
```

Comment: Great - This works perfekt...select *
from wccrm_kunden
where not exists (select 1  
                  from wccrm_anprobe
                  where ordered = 1
                  and wccrm_kunden.id = wccrm_anprobe.uid)
group by wccrm_kunden.id

Comment: This works indeed.. But this is a correlated subquery  these types of subquerys are slow on larger datasets.. Using NOT IN would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use NOT IN

```
SELECT
 *
FROM 
 [table]
WHERE 
 uid NOT IN ( 
  SELECT 
   uid
  FROM 
   [table]
  WHERE
   ordered = 1   
 )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I close this case?

Comment: @Bosstone dont know never asked a question so i dont know how to accept a answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        select *
from wccrm_kunden
where not exists (select 1  
                  from wccrm_anprobe
                  where ordered = 1
                  and wccrm_kunden.id = wccrm_anprobe.uid)
group by wccrm_kunden.id
```